# Why don't arrows keys work in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard

Watch this video.

http://screencast.com/t/SRyUxusqQ

In this video, you are seeing me press the down arrow three times, and the up arrow three times.  It might have been reversed, I don't remember.  In any case, the up/down/left/right arrows don't work in Microsoft Excel 2007.  I'm guessing I have a preference somewhere that's causing this, but I can't figure out what it could be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> enabled. Press the key again to disable this feature.

Comment: Haha!  You're a frickin' genius!  I'm just going to say "MacGruber"..

Comment: It won't let me accept right now.  I will in the morning.

Comment: Very common issue.